# SQL Change output of column if duplicate

Tags: sql, count, duplicates, subquery, case

I have a table which has rows for each product that a customer has purchased. I want to output a column from a SELECT query which shows the time it takes to deliver said item based on whether the customer has other items that need to be delivered. The first item takes 5 mins to deliver and all subsequent items take 2 mins to deliver e.g. 3 items would take 5+2+2=9 mins to deliver.

This is what I have at the moment(Using the Northwind sample database on w3schools to test the query):

```
SELECT orders.customerid, 
       orders.orderid, 
       orderdetails.productid, 
       CASE((SELECT Count(orders.customerid) 
             FROM   orders 
             GROUP  BY orders.customerid)) 
         WHEN 1 THEN '00:05' 
         ELSE '00:02' 
       END AS DeliveryTime 
FROM   orders 
       LEFT JOIN orderdetails 
              ON orderdetails.orderid = orders.orderid
```

This outputs '00:05' for every item due to the COUNT in my subquery(I think?), any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gregory's answer works a treat and here's my attempts

```
-- Without each product line item listed
SELECT  O.CustomerId, 
        O.OrderId, 
        COUNT(*) AS 'NumberOfProductsOrderd',  
        CASE COUNT(*)
            WHEN 1 THEN 5
            ELSE (COUNT(*) * 2) + 3
        END AS 'MinutesToDeliverAllProducts'
FROM Orders AS O
    INNER JOIN OrderDetails AS D ON D.OrderId = O.OrderId
GROUP BY O.CustomerId, O.OrderId

-- Without each product line item listed
SELECT  O.CustomerId, 
        O.OrderId, 
        D.ProductId,
        CASE 
            WHEN P.ProductsInOrder = 1 THEN 5
            ELSE (P.ProductsInOrder * 2) + 3
        END AS 'MinutesToDeliverAllProducts'
FROM Orders AS O
    INNER JOIN OrderDetails AS D ON D.OrderId = O.OrderId
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT OrderId, COUNT(*) AS ProductsInOrder
        FROM OrderDetails
        GROUP BY OrderId
    )  AS P ON P.OrderId = O.OrderId
GROUP BY O.CustomerId, 
        O.OrderId, 
        D.ProductId,
        P.ProductsInOrder
```

Comment: Where each product is listed on a separate row I'm still having the same problem but I've used your first query and added a group_concat to show all the product IDs for each order and this a great alternative, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT orders.customerid, 
       orders.orderid, 
       orderdetails.productid, 
       numberorders, 
       2 * ( numberorders - 1 ) + 5 AS deleveryMinutes 
FROM   orders 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT orders.customerid AS countId, 
                          Count(1)          AS numberOrders 
                   FROM   orders 
                   GROUP  BY orders.customerid) t1 
               ON t1.countid = orders.customerid 
       LEFT JOIN orderdetails 
              ON orderdetails.orderid = orders.orderid 
ORDER  BY customerid
```

Comment: This unfortunately outputs the same number for each row instead of outputting 5 for the first row and 2 for subsequent rows. I've played around a bit to see if I could get it to work but I think the problem lies with having each product on a new row so I think the solution will be as Kane has suggested below.

Comment: Sorry I must have misunderstood what you were logging for.  I thought you wanted the delivery time for all the products. "e.g. 3 items would take 5+2+2=9 mins"  I am glad Kane's answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Final code is below for anyone interested:

```
SELECT  O.CustomerId, 
        O.OrderId, 
        Group_Concat(D.ProductID) AS ProductID,  
        CASE COUNT(*)
            WHEN 1 THEN 5
            ELSE (COUNT(*) * 2) + 3
        END AS 'MinutesToDeliverAllProducts'
FROM Orders AS O
    INNER JOIN OrderDetails AS D ON D.OrderId = O.OrderId
GROUP BY O.CustomerId
```